# Does readony VS const make any sense if I live in Nuget world?

Tags: c#, .net

I know the differences between const & readonly and the side effects when I patch/deploy assemblies where const values are changed, without recompiling referencing assemblies.

But I just wondering if I should bother about them when I live in Nuget world?

Since my development flow goes through the Nuget - If assembly A is referencing assembly B and I want new changes from B, I just go ahead and update it via Nuget. I mean I'm not patching/deploying dlls to folders.

Looks like in Nuget scenarios these side effects are no more issue.

What do You think?

Comment: Whether or not you are changing `const` or `readonly` has no effect on what is considered a _newer_ assembly let alone the impact on a NuGet publication

Comment: Suppose you reference nuget packages A and B. B declares some constants. A also references B and uses those constants. Now new version of B comes which changes values of some constants, but no new version of A. Now A is using old (no longer there) values of constants from B package.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are in enclosed to a scenario where your development process only considers new versions of your base DLL being deployed when all the references are recompiled... **and I mean a full build**.

That might not be the case if the developer upgrades the DLL via Nuget, *does not change the code on his project* (so that the compiler does not need to update the previously compiled objects).

I suggest you to make some tests with this scenario, specially if you are relaying that users upgrade theses DLLs without any code modification from their DLLs.